# The puzzled wife

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge, story

A lengthy question

Once, a woman was getting ready to have a look at three suitors who had come to extend their wishes of marriage "A," "B" and "C."

When she was getting ready, a poisonous snake bit her and she died.

"A" decided to move from village to village taking her ashes with him.

"B" decided to do the last rites.

"C" stayed back mourning.

The maiden was an expert in religious matters

One day, "A" went to an old man's house

The old man told him how he can bring her back to life.

The man even showed it practically by killing his goat and then bringing it back to life.

"A" did the exact saying and brought her back to life.

The question is Whom will the maiden marry, "A," "B" or "C" and why?

> Hint: The answer lies in the line that the woman was an expert in religious matters

Comment: But simple what

Comment: i removed the word

Comment: It is based on the famous( in Indian subcontinent) _Vikram_ and _Vetala_  stories...and hence the answer is obvious. :P

Comment: You can reanimate someone who's been cremated? (Or were they the ashes from her fireplace that he cleaned up before selling her house?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It goes that

> A person who mourns one's death (that is C, here) is the real husband/ can be married.

As,

> As per concerned religious matters (subject to their applicability near Indian subcontinent regions), the one who performs last rites is equivalent to her *son* and one who brings her back to life is equivalent to her *father*.

Saying the above, few additional tags are really applicable to this puzzle, such as

> Knowledge and *India* (if available)

Comment: Why is it that her father and son would have "come to extend their wishes of marriage"?

Comment: Agreed, a nice *catch*. The original story ( if interested, you may look at a detailed version of one of the stories of _Vikarm & Bhethal_ epic) is slightly different but also, coming back to the context, the same suitors *turn* into / treated as different kinds of relationships (with her) based on the deeds they perform, post her death - again, as per local sentiments/ religious prescriptions.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Yes it is from the Vikram and Betal epic but it is unknown to others from the world that is why I posted it

Comment: Moreover the India tag is not available

Answer (score 4):

The maiden will marry suitor

> B

Because

> She cares a lot about religious matters, and B was the only one who performed a religious ceremony after she died. C didn't do anything really, and A likely went against the ideas of the religion by bringing her back after the Last Rites were performed.

Comment: No, that could have been it but that is not what is expected. Nevertheless a good attempt

Comment: The answer somewhat lies in what each relative does after a person's demise

Comment: Wow, a nice answer - involving _lateral _thinking_ applied. +1.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is:

> A

I think this because:

> The maiden was religious and A brought her back with a ritualistic "saying". This meant he believed in the saying and whatever religion it was, thus would be the maiden's choice.

Comment: good attempt but not the answer

Comment: I like this answer the best, I think it's the most clever and the one that follows most directly from the information provided. "Is an expert on religious matters" is a non-deterministic clue (not to mention SUPER lame) unless you tell us which religion she adheres to :|